# Работа с магическими методами

Tags: php, ооп, методы

Я только учу ООП в PHP, не нужно меня строго судить за не правильные термины

Есть такое задание:

> 1). Добавьте в класс Point метод **__toString()** и реализуйте его,
> вернув строку такого вида: «Точка с координатами (x, y)». Вместо **X**
> и **Y** должны быть конкретные значения.
>
> 2). Создайте **3** разных **объекта** класса и выведите их через
> **echo**.
>
> 3). Реализуйте метод **__get()**, в котором при обращении к
> несуществующему свойству **Z** будет выведено сообщение «Класс
> работает только в двумерном пространстве»
>
> 4). Аналогично сделайте метод **__set()** при попытке изменить свойств
> **Z**.
>
> 5). Реализуйте метод **call()**, в котором выведите ту же строку, что
> и в **пункте 3**, при попытке вызвать метод **setZ()**.
>
> 6). Создайте **1 объект** класса Point и сделайте его **клон**.
> Убедитесь, что клонирование прошло успешно, попытавшись изменить
> свойство любого из объектов и выведя это свойство у обоих объектов.
> Они должны быть различны.

Вот мое решение:

```
<?php
class Point {
    
    private $x;
    private $y;
    
    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
    
    public function __toString() {
        $coordinatePoints =  '(' . $this->x . ', ' . $this->y . ')';
        return $coordinatePoints;
    }
    
    public function __get($z) {
        if (isset($this->z)) return $this->z;
        return 'Класс <u>PointTaskSeven</u> работает только в двумерном пространстве';
    }
    
    public function __set($z, $value) {
        if (isset($this->z)) return $this->z;
        return 'Класс <u>PointTaskSeven</u> работает только в двумерном пространстве';
    }
    
    public function __call($method, $z) {
        return 'Класс <u>PointTaskSeven</u> работает только в двумерном пространстве; <u>Переданные параметры: '  . $method . '(' . implode(', ', $z) . ')</u>';
    }
    
    public function __clone() {
        $this->x = 95;
        $this->y = 75;
    }
}

$pointOne = new Point(12, 24);
echo "Объект#1 => Точки координат $pointOne;<br>";

$pointTwo = new Point(48, 64);
echo "Объект#2 => Точки координат $pointTwo;<br>";

$pointThree = new Point(128, 256);
echo "Объект#3 => Точки координат $pointThree;<br>";

echo 'Обращение к Z => ' . $pointThree->z . ';<br>';

echo 'echo: Изминение Z => ' . $pointThree->z = 15 . ';<br>';

echo 'echo: Обращение к setZ() =>' . $pointThree->setZ(12, 24, 48) . ';<br>';

$point = new Point(512, 1024);
echo "Объект#4 => Точки координат $pointTaskSeven;<br>";

$clonePoint = clone $point;
echo 'Клон->Объекта#4 => Точки координат ' . $clonePoint . ';<br>';
?>
```

Результат:

```
Объект#1 => Точки координат (12, 24);
Объект#2 => Точки координат (48, 64);
Объект#3 => Точки координат (128, 256);
Обращение к Z => Класс PointTaskSeven работает только в двумерном пространстве;
Изменение Z => 15;
Обращение к setZ() => Класс PointTaskSeven работает только в двумерном пространстве; Переданные параметры: setZ(12, 24, 48);
Объект#4 => Точки координат (512, 1024);
Клон->Объекта#4 => Точки координат (95, 75);
```

В моем решении не работают корректно пункт **4).**

Пункт **4).** дает такой ответ `Изменение Z => 15;`

> Есть две точки **X** и **Y** с модификатором доступа **private**. Конструктор чтобы получить свойство **Z** обращается к **__get()** - «*гетеру*», где свойства **Z** не получает, выдается сообщение, что класс работает в
> двумерном пространстве.
>
> После конструктор обращается к **__set()** - «*сетеру*», и
> устанавливает значение **Z** равное **15**.
>
> Мои мысли по работе кода и почему вывелось **15**. В задании нужно
> вывести ошибку о работе в двумерном пространстве как понял, при
> отсутствии свойства **Z**. Как исправить не понимаю

Помогите разобраться с двумя пунктами **4).**

Comment: Класс `Point` очевидно должен обладать пропертями `x` и `y`. А не какой-то там `coordinatePoints`.

Comment: Я понимаю, если добавить два свойства `private $x;` и `private $y;` то `__set()` ничего установить не сможет. Пока не добавить запись `$this->z = $z;` в конструктор, надеюсь не чушь пишу. В том то и задача, что хочу это усложнить массивом `$coordinatePoints;`.

Comment: Не понимаю зачем минус ставить за не понимание. Все экспертами родились что ли? Дизморалить легче, чем помочь. Я не написал две строчки и жду ответ, а проявляю интерес к решению задачи

Comment: Успокоил свой пыл, смерился, что новичок, и ставить не решаемые задачи рано. Запретить `PHP` добавлять значение в массив - плохая затея, не имеющая смысла. Переделал решение с двумя свойствами `private $x;` и `private $y;` как подметил `u_mulder`. Однако все равно  `__set()` добавляет третью координату и выводит её

Comment: `__set` работает верно, 15 выводится не от координаты а от присваивания.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду, что `__get()` установил переменную, и вывел. В образе задачи летаю, координаты и т.д. Значит я не правильно задание понял выходит? `4). Аналогично сделайте метод __set() при попытке изменить свойств Z.`

Comment: @StudyingAgain Цитата из документации `Возвращаемое значение __set() будет проигнорировано из-за способа обработки в PHP оператора присваивания.`

Comment: Используйте метод property_exists(), т.к. isset() бесполезен для определения наличия свойства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит как-то так:

```
class Point {
    
    private $x;
    private $y;
    
    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
    
    public function __toString() {
        return 'Точка с координатами (' . $this->x . ', ' . $this->y . ')';
    }
    
    public function __get($var) {
        if ('x' === $var || 'y' === $var) {
            return $this->$var;
        }

        return 'Класс <u>PointTaskSeven</u> работает только в двумерном пространстве';
    }
    
    public function __set($var, $value) {
        if ('x' === $var || 'y' === $var) {
            $this->$var = $value;
            return;
        }

        echo 'Класс <u>PointTaskSeven</u> работает только в двумерном пространстве';
    }
    
    public function __call($method, $argument) {
        if ('setZ' === $method) {
            echo 'Класс <u>PointTaskSeven</u> работает только в двумерном пространстве';
        }
    }
}

$pointOne = new Point(12, 24);
echo "Объект#1 => $pointOne;<br>";

$pointTwo = new Point(48, 64);
echo "Объект#2 => $pointTwo;<br>";

$pointThree = new Point(128, 256);
echo "Объект#3 => $pointThree;<br>";

echo 'Обращение к Z:<br>';
echo $pointThree->z;

echo "<br>";

echo 'Изменение Z:<br>';
$pointThree->z = 15;

echo "<br>";

echo 'Обращение к setZ()<br>';
$pointThree->setZ(12);

echo "<br>";

$point = new Point(512, 1024);
$clonePoint = clone $point;
$clonePoint->x = 102;

echo "Объект#4 => $point;<br>";
echo "Клон->Объекта#4 => $clonePoint;<br>";
```

Comment: Думал уже вопрос буду удалять, раз туплю так и ответ где-то перед носом в документации искать надо. Спасибо за развернутый ответ!